# SQL query to filter out 1 subcategory from acategory

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data in table in which one column is called `Platform` and another one is called `OS`.

Values could be something like this:

```
---------------------------
| Word  | Platform  | OS  |
---------------------------
| Word1 |  App.        | iOS
| Word2 |  App.        | Android
| Word3 |  Desktop.    | Chrome
| Word4 |  Mobile Site | iOS
```

Till now my query was

```
Select * from tbl where Length(Word) > 1 AND Platform != App
```

so it would output

```
---------------------------
| Word  | Platform  | OS  |
---------------------------
| Word3 |  Desktop.    | Chrome
| Word4 |  Mobile Site | iOS
```

Now I want to include `App` platform but only for `iOS` and Other OS like Windows, Android is still not needed

so my output looks like

```
 ---------------------------
   | Word  | Platform  | OS  |
   ---------------------------
   | Word1 |  App.        | iOS
   | Word3 |  Desktop.    | Chrome
   | Word4 |  Mobile Site | iOS
```

I am not getting how to update the query. Any inputs would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

It will select App platform for iOS

```
Select * from tbl where Length(Word) > 1 AND (Platform != 'App.' OR (Platform == 'App.' AND os = 'iOS' ))
```

[Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/eb028/1/0)

Comment: Thank you , This is helpful. It was easy

Comment: It's my pleasure 